# How to gather files from other apps in my React Native app with a simple iOS action extension?

Tags: ios, react-native, share-extension

This seems to be more difficult than I thought. I want to build an iOS action extension that accepts ZIP files and puts them somewhere so they can be read by my main app.

Looks like I'll have to set up an App Group for the main app and the share extension. However, `react-native-fs` does not seem to be able to read from the resulting shared directory (considering what is available here: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#constants).

And the regular `AsyncStorage` does not seem to be able to accomplish this either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I now have found this closed issue on `react-native-fs` that addresses exactly what I'm trying to do: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/278

Implementing that now and will edit this answer with any interesting gotchas as they emerge.